# Код кнопки OnClick через другую кнопку

Tags: delphi, button, delphi-7, click

Есть две формы. Одна главная, на ней имеется несколько кнопок к переходу на вторую форму. Вторая форма шаблонная: все поля и кнопки для заполнения в ней пустые. Как присвоить код действия кнопки из шаблонной формы на кнопку из главной. Что нужно прописать на //STR[9] чтобы button1 присвоил код, описанный ниже этой строки?

```
procedure TForm4.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form5.Caption:= 'Add New Value';
Form5.DBLookupListBox1.ListSource:=Form4.DS_country;
Form5.DBLookupListBox1.ListField:='Country;Country_ID';
Form5.DBLookupListBox1.KeyField:=('Country_ID');
Form5.DBEdit1.DataSource:=Form4.DS_country;
Form5.DBEdit1.DataField:=('Country');

                                             //STR[9]**               Form5.Button1 (?????)**

begin
 Form4.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
Form4.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Select Country from ВИД WHERE Country='+#39+Form5.Edit1.Text+#39);
Form4.ADOQuery1.Open;
if Form4.ADOQuery1.IsEmpty then
  begin
  Form4.Query_vid.Insert;
  Form4.Query_vid.FieldByName('Country').AsString := Form5.Edit1.Text;
  Form4.Query_vid.Open;
  Form4.Query_vid.Post;
  MessageBox(Handle, 'new data was entered','Add New Value',MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  end
 else
  begin
  Form4.Query_vid.Cancel;
  Form4.ADOQuery1.Cancel;
  MessageBox(Handle,PChar(''+Form5.Edit1.text+'is already on the list'),'Ошибка',MB_ICONWARNING);
  end;
end;
```

Дело в том, что все значения у всех компонентов в шаблонной форме пустые, и я хочу чтобы они заполнялись только после того как будет нажата определенная кнопка из главной формы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

События в Delphi это обычные свойства со ссылкой на объектную процедуру, значить их можно присваивать.

Для начала из кода необходимо сделать объектную процедуру с параметрами как у события.

```
procedure TForm4.MyButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Form4.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
Form4.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Select Country from ВИД WHERE Country='+#39+Form5.Edit1.Text+#39);
Form4.ADOQuery1.Open;
if Form4.ADOQuery1.IsEmpty then
  begin
  Form4.Query_vid.Insert;
  Form4.Query_vid.FieldByName('Country').AsString := Form5.Edit1.Text;
  Form4.Query_vid.Open;
  Form4.Query_vid.Post;
  MessageBox(Handle, 'new data was entered','Add New Value',MB_ICONINFORMATION);
  end
 else
  begin
  Form4.Query_vid.Cancel;
  Form4.ADOQuery1.Cancel;
  MessageBox(Handle,PChar(''+Form5.Edit1.text+'is already on the list'),'Ошибка',MB_ICONWARNING);
  end;
end;
```

Затем присвоение

```
Form5.Button1.Onclick := Form4.MyButtonClick;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Сработало.